# Switch from \mathds{1} to \mathbb{1} without the use of bbold package

Tags: fonts, pdftex, symbols, packages

For my book I use for identity matrix the package `dsfont`, with the command `\mathds{1}`. With this MWE, evidently,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bb=boondox]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{futm}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{futm}{m}{n}{
  <-> s * [.95] fourier-bb
  }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{Ufutm}{U}{futm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{Ufutm}

\begin{document}
$\mathbb{1}$
\end{document}
```

I obtain this image:

[image]

I'd like to get this instead.

[image]

I can not into my book, for font contrast, to use `bbold` package. I hope that this file can be useful http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/mathpackages/amsfonts-symbols.pdf.

Greetings everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the other glyph with a new alphabet, but imho it looks simply bad. The proportions don't fit.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} %%%%%% *This package can be omitted*
\usepackage[bb=boondox]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{futm}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{futm}{m}{n}{
  <-> s * [.95] fourier-bb
  }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{Ufutm}{U}{futm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{Ufutm}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbb}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
$\mathbbb{1} \mathbb{Z}  \mathbbb{Q} \mathbb{1}\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Q}$
\end{document}
```

[image]